# SQL Server 2012 Bulk Upload Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulk-load

I'm new in SQL. I don't really know why the import wizard won't work so I end up importing using the bulk load. It did work for the rest of my files but with one which is the biggest so far is giving me this error

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file. 
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 18 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Can anyone give me hand on this please?

Comment: the last record propably has no end-of-record delimiter.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the file worked flawless with another machine using the wizard but in my laptop it gave me this error.

Comment: Do you have a linked server set up on your laptop?

Comment: No I don't have. It's just a stand alone laptop installed with sql server 2012 express. It is really weird coz the other machine installed with the same sql server 2012 express. The files works perfectly on a wizard import. But this laptop the import doesnt work and the bulk upload doesnt work on this file only but the other files is fine.

Comment: Do the two PCs have different operating systems - including 32/64 bit versions of the same OS version?  Are the two PCs loading the same file, or are they two supposedly identical files generated separately on each PC?

Comment: Both PC's are running on windows 7. The PC that wouldnt bulk is 64bit and the other one which is ok is 32 bit. The file i'm uploading is identical which has a size of nearly 400MB.Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks so much for your interest of helping me. Very much appreciated. I did managed to find a way. Actually Monty Wild gave me an idea about the Bit of the OS. What i did is to re extract to CSV file on a windows 7 32 bit. And do the the bulk import on my windows 7 64bit. The trick did it. Both system installed with SQL Server 2012 Express. The original file was created on a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise running on a windows server 2008.Thanks once again for all your help. Jhun